# Adding a new field to an entity

Tags: java, android, android-room, database-migration

I have created a `director` class

```
@Entity(tableName = "director")
public class Director {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "did")
    public int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "full_name")
    @NonNull
    public String fullName;


    public Director(@NonNull String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }
}
```

I decided to add a new column by adding a migration method and adding a field to the class

```
@Entity(tableName = "director")
public class Director {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "did")
    public int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "full_name")
    @NonNull
    public String fullName;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "age")
    public int age;

    public Director(@NonNull String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }
}
```

the method

```
static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {

        String query = "ALTER TABLE 'director' ADD COLUMN 'age' INTEGER ";

        database.execSQL(query);

    }
};
```

When I execute the code I get this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle
```

And it says it expected

```
age=Column{name='year', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}},
```

And found

```
age=Column{name='year', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'},
```

I can see the problem is on the "notnull" part but how to fix this? I want it to be null.

Comment: There is a thing that for the non-null values you have to provide default values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the default age value to 0

```
 static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {

  @Override
  public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(
      "ALTER TABLE 'director' ADD COLUMN 'age' INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0"
     );
  }
};
```